# PHP - Only Certain Values of Array Indexed Input Fields Being Posted?

Tags: php

I have a PHP based web page with many input fields. Some of the input, logically, can be expressed as arrays of related "objects"; specifically I have three such object arrays - one for "beneficiaries", one for "children", and one for "vision". The basic format of the input fields is as follows:

```
<input name='object[index][property]' />
```

For example

```
<input type='text'  data-confirm='beneficiary0CityDisplay'  name='beneficiary[0][city]' class='required' />
```

When the data is posted, I am expecting to receive arrays of objects each with several properties; for example, an array of four "beneficiaries" with properties city, state, and the like. This actually works as expected for two of three object groups noted above; however, all the objects for the "child" array only have two properties. To illustrate, my beneficiary array is as follows:

[image]

This is how it should be; each "vision" object has eight properties (yes, they are empty at present, but that is expected). The same is true for the beneficiary data. However, only two properties of the child data is being posted:

[image]

I am perplexed as to why this is. Not only due all the child input fields seem to share the same syntax/naming convention, but so do the beneficiary and vision input fields.

For example, this works:

```
    <td><input type='text' data-confirm='vision0FirstDisplay' name='vision[0][firstName]'
                placeholder='First' /> <input type='text'
            data-confirm='vision0LastDisplay'   name='vision[0][lastName]' placeholder='Last' /></td>
            <td><input data-confirm='vision0SSNDisplay'  maxlength=9 type='text' name='vision[0][ssn]' class='ssn' /></td>
                        <td><select data-confirm='vision0GenderDisplay' name='vision[0][gender]'>
                        <option value=''>...</option>
                <option value='M'>Male</option>
                <option value='F'>Female</option>
        </select></td>
            <td><select data-confirm='vision0MonthDisplay' name='vision[0][month]'>
                    <option value=''>Month</option>
                    <option value='01'>01</option>
                    <option value='02'>02</option>
                    <option value='03'>03</option>
                    <option value='04'>04</option>
                    <option value='05'>05</option>
                    <option value='06'>06</option>
                    <option value='07'>07</option>
                    <option value='08'>08</option>
                    <option value='09'>09</option>
                    <option value='10'>10</option>
                    <option value='11'>11</option>
                    <option value='12'>12</option>
            </select> <input type='text' data-confirm='vision0DayDisplay' name='vision[0][day]' class='day'
                placeholder='Day' /> <input type='text' data-confirm='vision0YearDisplay' name='vision[0][year]'
                class='year' placeholder='Yr.' /></td>


            <td><select class='visionRelationship' data-confirm='vision0RelationshipDisplay' name='vision[0][relationship]'>
                            <option
                                value=''>Select</option>
                            <option value='Spouse'>Spouse
                            </option>
                            <option value='Dependent'>Dependent </option>
                            </select>
                            </td>
        </tr>

                                    <tr>
            <td><input type='text' data-confirm='vision1FirstDisplay' name='vision[1][firstName]'
                placeholder='First' /> <input type='text'
            data-confirm='vision1LastDisplay'   name='vision[1][lastName]' placeholder='Last' /></td>
            <td><input data-confirm='vision1SSNDisplay' maxlength=9 type='text' name='vision[1][ssn]' class='ssn' /></td>
                        <td><select data-confirm='vision1GenderDisplay' name='vision[1][gender]'>
                <option value=''>...</option>
                <option value='M'>Male</option>
                <option value='F'>Female</option>
        </select></td>
            <td><select data-confirm='vision1MonthDisplay' name='vision[1][month]'>
                    <option value=''>Month</option>
                    <option value='01'>01</option>
                    <option value='02'>02</option>
                    <option value='03'>03</option>
                    <option value='04'>04</option>
                    <option value='05'>05</option>
                    <option value='06'>06</option>
                    <option value='07'>07</option>
                    <option value='08'>08</option>
                    <option value='09'>09</option>
                    <option value='10'>10</option>
                    <option value='11'>11</option>
                    <option value='12'>12</option>
            </select> <input type='text' data-confirm='vision1DayDisplay' name='vision[1][day]' class='day'
                placeholder='Day' /> <input type='text' data-confirm='vision1YearDisplay' name='vision[1][year]'
                class='year' placeholder='Yr.' /></td>
```

this (except for the state and zip fields), does not:

```
    <td><input placeholder="First" type='text' data-confirm='child0FirstDisplay'  name='child[0][firstName]' />
            <input placeholder="Last" type='text' data-confirm='child0LastDisplay' name='child[0][lastName]' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' class='ssn'  maxlength=9 data-confirm='child0SSNDisplay' name='child[0][ssn]' /></td>
        <td><select name="child[0][month]" data-confirm='child0MonthDisplay'>
                <option value=''>Month</option>
                <option value='01'>01</option>
                <option value='02'>02</option>
                <option value='03'>03</option>
                <option value='04'>04</option>
                <option value='05'>05</option>
                <option value='06'>06</option>
                <option value='07'>07</option>
                <option value='08'>08</option>
                <option value='09'>09</option>
                <option value='10'>10</option>
                <option value='11'>11</option>
                <option value='12'>12</option>
        </select> <input placeholder='Day' type='text' data-confirm='child0DayDisplay' name='child[0][day]'
            class='day' /> <input placeholder='Yr.' type='text'
            name='child[0][year]' data-confirm='child0YearDisplay'  class='year' /></td>
        <td><select  data-confirm='child0GenderDisplay' name='child[0][gender]'>
        <option value=''>...</option>
                <option value='M'>Male</option>
                <option value='F'>Female</option>
        </select></td>
        <td><input type='checkbox' data-confirm='child0HandicapDisplay' name='child[0][isHandicap]' /> Handicap <input
            type='checkbox' data-confirm='child0StudentDisplay' name='child[0][isStudent]' /> Student <input
            type='checkbox' data-confirm='child0FosterDisplay' name='child[0][isFoster]' /> Foster <input
            type='checkbox' data-confirm='child0StepDisplay' name='child[0][isStep]' /> Step-Child</td>


        <td>Check if your <em>child</em> has a different address than yours.
            <input type='checkbox' class='childAddressCheckbox'
            name='child[0]diffAddress' />
            <div class='childAddressContainer'>
                <input type='text' data-confirm='child0StreetDisplay' name='child[0]address'
                    placeholder='Street Address' /> <input type='text'
                    name='child[0]city' data-confirm='child0CityDisplay' placeholder='City' /> <select
                    id='child[0][state]' data-confirm='child0StateDisplay' name="child[0][state]">
                    /// STATES HERE ///
                </select> <input type='text' name='child[0][zip]' class='zip' />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>


<tr>
        <td><input placeholder="First" type='text' data-confirm='child1FirstDisplay'  name='child[1][firstName]' />
            <input placeholder="Last" type='text' data-confirm='child1LastDisplay' name='child[1][lastName]' /></td>
        <td><input type='text'  maxlength=9 class='ssn' data-confirm='child1SSNDisplay' name='child[1][ssn]' /></td>
        <td><select name="child[1][month]" data-confirm='child1MonthDisplay' >
                <option value=''>Month</option>
                <option value='01'>01</option>
                <option value='02'>02</option>
                <option value='03'>03</option>
                <option value='04'>04</option>
                <option value='05'>05</option>
                <option value='06'>06</option>
                <option value='07'>07</option>
                <option value='08'>08</option>
                <option value='09'>09</option>
                <option value='10'>10</option>
                <option value='11'>11</option>
                <option value='12'>12</option>
        </select> <input placeholder='Day' type='text' data-confirm='child1DayDisplay' name='child[1][day]'
            class='day' /> <input placeholder='Yr.' type='text'
            name='child[1][year]' data-confirm='child1YearDisplay'  class='year' /></td>
        <td><select  data-confirm='child1GenderDisplay' name='child[1][gender]'>
        <option value=''>...</option>
                <option value='M'>Male</option>
                <option value='F'>Female</option>
        </select></td>
        <td><input type='checkbox' data-confirm='child1HandicapDisplay' name='child[1][isHandicap]' /> Handicap <input
            type='checkbox' data-confirm='child1StudentDisplay' name='child[1][isStudent]' /> Student <input
            type='checkbox' data-confirm='child1FosterDisplay' name='child[1][isFoster]' /> Foster <input
            type='checkbox' data-confirm='child1StepDisplay' name='child[1][isStep]' /> Step-Child</td>


        <td>Check if your <em>child</em> has a different address than yours.
            <input type='checkbox' class='childAddressCheckbox'
            name='child[1]diffAddress' />
            <div class='childAddressContainer'>
                <input type='text' data-confirm='child1StreetDisplay' name='child[1]address'
                    placeholder='Street Address' /> <input type='text'
                    name='child[1]city' data-confirm='child1CityDisplay' placeholder='City' /> <select
                    id='child[1][state]' data-confirm='child1StateDisplay' name="child[1][state]">
                /// STATES HERE ///
                </select> <input type='text' name='child[1][zip]' class='zip' />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

It is probably something simple, but I am a bit stumped at the moment; any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not being consistent with your name properties:
`child[1]city` vs `child[1][state]`

the correct syntax for posting fields so they are available as arrays in $_POST is with square brackets wrapping keys so `child[1][state]` is correct whereas `child[1]city` is not.

Also worth noting that checkboxes are only posted when they are checked.